# Select last message from each member

Tags: php, mysql, select, request, last-modified

I want to display the last message from each user.
I wrote this MySQL request but it displays the last message from one user, and the first messages from other users. I don't understand why.

```
SELECT *
FROM cbadminmessages
   INNER JOIN cbmembres ON cbadminmessages.id_membre_message=cbmembres.id
WHERE id!='$admin_id'
AND id_message IN(
    SELECT MAX(id_message)
    FROM cbadminmessages
    GROUP BY id_membre_message)
ORDER BY id_message");
```

`id_message` is the message's id.
`id_membre_message` is the member's ID who wrote the message.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery seems to be incorrect. You should refer to the outer tables to select the maximum for each specific user. Also, using table aliases will help a great deal.

```
SELECT ad.id_membre_message, ad.id_message #and anything else you'd like to select
FROM cbadminmessages ad
INNER JOIN cbmembres mem
ON ad.id_membre_message=mem.id
WHERE mem.id!='$admin_id'
AND ad.id_message = (
    SELECT MAX(ad_sub.id_message)
    FROM cbadminmessages ad_sub
    WHERE ad_sub.id_membre_message = mem.id)
ORDER BY ad.id_message");
```